# Выполнить действия активных чекбоксов по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox

Есть такая последовательность:

1. Выделить все необходимые чекбоксы,
2. Нажать на кнопку, которая выполнит методы в зависимости от выбранных чекбоксов (например, выбраны чекбоксы 1, 2 и 5, поэтому выполняются методы 1, 2, и 5 соответственно)

Делать через конструкцию if else будет неудобно, поскольку таких checkbox'ов очень много. Была мысль вешать методы на каждое событие checked, но я не понимаю, как мне экономно проверить все чекбоксы.

Answer (score 6):

Пора отучиться от привычки везде и всегда использовать if/else конструкции.
Объявим Dictionary с нужными нам чек боксами с формы:

```
Dictionary<CheckBox, Action> CheckBoxes;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CheckBoxes = new Dictionary<CheckBox, Action>
    {
        [checkBox1] = () => Console.WriteLine(1),
        [checkBox2] = () => Console.WriteLine(2),
        [checkBox3] = () => Console.WriteLine(3),
        [checkBox4] = () => Console.WriteLine(4),
        [checkBox5] = () => Console.WriteLine(5),
        [checkBox6] = () => Console.WriteLine(6),
        [checkBox7] = () => Console.WriteLine(7),
        [checkBox8] = () => Console.WriteLine(8),
        [checkBox9] = () => Console.WriteLine(9),
        [checkBox10] = () => Console.WriteLine(10),
        [checkBox11] = method11,
    };
}
```

Опишем method11:

```
void method11()
{
    Console.WriteLine(11);
}
```

А теперь реализуем нажатие на кнопку:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var item in CheckBoxes.Where(x => x.Key.Checked).Select(x => x.Value))
    {
        item?.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Отмечаем любые/все чек боксы на форме и наблюдаем за окном вывода.